# How do you stop an adjacent face from moving?

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm new to Blender, and really need some help.

I'm following a tutorial, where you have a cube, and you use extrude region on one side of the cube so you end up with two cubes next to each other. You then select the top face of one of the cubes and push it downwards.

In the tutorial the cube you don't touch remains as it was, so you have two cubes of different heights.

However, when I do this the top surface of the cube  I'm not moving, adjusts to my movement and slopes so the top half is like a triangle.

How do I stop the adjacent cube from changing it's shape when I adjust the height of the cube next to it?

I'm not sure if it would affect it or not, but proportional editing is disabled.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Here is an photo of the part of the tutorial, it is from a magazine.

[image]

Step 8 says: You can move one face around independently of the adjoining face. Try pushing one of the adjacent faces downwards and notice that Blender fills the space between them with another surface.

Comment: Can you put the link of the video/tutorial?

Comment: It would be easier to do simply duplicating the cube. What are the steps before the 7-th and 8-th? And what is the version of Blender used in magazine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because both of cube faces share same vertexes. you probably missed some extrusion in the tutorial.

Starting from simple cube click `E` followed by `Esc`
then extrude normally (click `E` again and move your mouse to extrude the face.

[image]

You can notice extra dots in the place cubes meet.

Then just simply select top face and push it down:
[image]

Other way to get same result:

First select 2 vertexes those faces share:
[image]

When click `V` - (that is the hotkey for rip) followed by Enter (If you accidentally move the mouse and vertexes move, simply click `ctrl+z` to undo and try again.

Select the face and push it downwards:

[image]

Finally, select 4 vertexes and click `F` to fill up the hole with face

Comment: Thanks for your answer - what you suggest does work, but isn't how the tutorial suggests Blender should work. I've added a photo of the part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth : after using Blender for about a year, I have personally never encountered the behavior shown in that tutorial picture - that is to say, performing a "Sketchup-like" push and pull with an automatic fill.

A third-party add-on allowing for something of that nature has recently been released, but this is definitely not default. This probably means that this tutorial has been badly edited/proofread.